# Having trouble replicating and filtering out null values in an object

Tags: javascript, json

In Chrome inspector when I hove over my object, it looks like the following:

[image]

I have a jsfiddle below but I don't know if I built the object correctly and I'm getting an error about a missing } bracket.

Here's what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/pvzck2qb/3/

```
obj = {
  1: {
    null
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    obj1: {
      hello: 'world'
    }
  }
}


Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] != null).forEach((key) => {
  /* do stuff with key here */
  console.log(key);
})
```

Comment: It suppose to be: `obj = { 1: null, ...`

Comment: Can you post the *actual input object* you're working with so we can see if its syntax is correct and try to work with it? (don't post images of the input, post the actual input)

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in this line

```
1: {
    null
  },
```

The Object `1` need to have a key which is missing